# How to align text vertically with fixed textwidth?

Tags: xetex, align, textwidth

I'm lost on how to align text properly. Anything I search up with respect to `textwidth` only gives results on how formatting tables work, but I'm just trying to work with plain text here. Any idea what I'm getting wrong? I'm trying to work on a resume and was using a XeLaTeX example that I found online. Any help appreciated.

PS. I have 0 experience with LaTeX and everyone says you have to learn by doing, so I guess I'm doing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}


% figure support
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\pdfminorversion=7
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}
\newcommand{\incfig}[1]{%
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \import{./figures/}{#1.pdf_tex}
}

\newcommand*{\entryskillstyle}[1]{{{\textwidth #1 50cm}\fontsize{15pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black} #1}}
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1

\begin{document}
\setlength{\entryskillstyle}{9cm}
\entryskillstyle{Hello \TeX world}
\entryskillstyle{Hello StackExchange world}
\end{document}
```

This is what I want it to look like with respect to alignment (excluding formatting) (it's maybe not clear in this example, but I want only "Hello TeX World" and "Hello StackExchange world" to be aligned, I don't care about the rest of the text):

```
Hello TeX World              I'm eating a salad
Hello StackExchange world    I'm eating a veggie burger
```

What I'm actually getting:

[image]

Comment: never ignore errors.  Your document produces `! Undefined control sequence` after _any_ error the typeset output is not intended to be useful, just a possible debuging aid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Hello \TeX\ world& I'm eating\ldots\\
Hello StackExchange world& I'm eating
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you get errors (your posted code gives undefined command errors) then the generated PDF is not intended to be useful. TeX only recovers from errors enough to debug the document it does not make any real attempt to make a sensible typeset output.

It is *much* easier to start from a simple document and only add packages if you need them. Most of the packages you are loading do not seem relevant and if you are using xelatex then you should never load `inputenc` or `fontenc`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't really understand what the errors were saying to be honest, and I don't really know what the packages were doing either, I just pasted it in from somewhere to get a working LaTeX document like I always did (I usually work with math so I use this header). I'm going to try and familiarize myself with what the different error messages and packages mean or do from now on. Didn't know what `inputenc` and `fontenc` did either, but now I will remember for sure! People around me are always saying I should stop reading theory and just do, haha..

Comment: @herophant if you work with math keep `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}` but the other packages you almost certainly do not need, or only need them in specific documents.